# Текущий поток должен быть задан как поток однопоточного контейнера

Tags: c#

Как-то через раз появляется ошибка:

> Текущий поток должен быть задан как поток однопоточного контейнера
>   (STA), чтобы вызовы OLE стали возможны. Проверьте, что ваша функция
>   Main помечена атрибутом STAThreadAttribute.

Что это значит и как исправить? И почему она выскакивает не всегда?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
 public static void Main() {
  try {
   TextReader file_track_title = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AMData\track_title.txt");

   System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(file_track_title.ReadLine());

   file_track_title.Close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(file_track_title.ReadLine()));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  ...
}
```

Судя по [докам](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), это надо для работы с COM

Comment: К сожалению, но не помогло.